# Left Shifting an array of ints

Tags: java, programming-challenge, circular-list

The problem I am referring to is [here](http://codingbat.com/prob/p105031)

So basically it's about shifting an array of ints 1 position to the left and relocating the lost first `int` in the start of the array to the last position at the right:

\$\mathrm{shiftLeft}(\{6, 2, 5, 3\}) → \{2, 5, 3, 6\}\$

\$\mathrm{shiftLeft}(\{1, 2\}) → \{2, 1\}\$

\$\mathrm{shiftLeft}(\{1\}) → \{1\}\$

Please feel free to review the code below:

```
public int[] shiftLeft(int[] nums) {
    for(int i = 0, start = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            start = nums[i];
        if(i == (nums.length -1))
        {
            nums[i] = start;
            break;
        }    
        nums[i] = nums[i + 1];
    }
    return nums;            
}
```

Also I would like to get rid of the variable start and try to solve it only using the loop iterator `i`, any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your current solution is actually pretty good, conceptually. There's nothing wrong with the `start` variable. I am not sure why you want to remove it. The loop is logically a good solution, but there's a better way than that, though (better because you can make the system do it for you....).

```
public int[] shiftLeft(int[] nums) {
    if (nums == null || nums.length <= 1) {
        return nums;
    }
    int start = nums[0];
    System.arraycopy(nums, 1, nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
    nums[nums.length - 1] = start;
    return nums;
}
```

Note that, in addition to using `System.arraycopy` I also check to see that the input has valid values available....

Comment: I'd omit the `nums == null` check. Your method is null-safe, but most Java methods are not, which means that the programmer must handle nulls somewhere. If they don't, they'll get an NPE and the sooner the better.

Comment: @rolfl`What if we want to shift it to right?`

Comment: @paul - then adjust the indices you see in the code to be in the other direction.... so, for example instead of `int start = nums[0]` have `int start = nums[nums.length - 1]`

Comment: what if we want to shift it 50 times to the left but array length is 20!? your solution would have a bug then I'd say.

Comment: @MonaJalal - well, no.... it has no bug. Your comment makes no sense. The original question is to only shift by 1, and there is not even an argument/parameter to specify any other shift distance. The only way to shift by 50 is to call the method 50 times, and it will work just fine then

Comment: @maaartinus Yes the programmer must handle null somewhere. That doesn't mean that functions shouldn't be defensive. With that logic where do you stop? If a function is safe and so doesn't need to check for NULL then *what function does*? And if it's the same program then what? If it's not then what? Maybe not relevant here but compilers (e.g. GCC) have ended up causing security holes because of optimising NULL pointer checks out. Whether that's the case here or no doesn't mean one should omit sanity checks.

Comment: @Pryftan My sanity check is `checkNotNull(nums)`. Let's call it "offensive programming" if you wish to. When every method throws on `null` input, then there'll be no `null`s anywhere and no NPEs as all such problems most probably get revealed rather immediately. When some methods accept `null` and some even pass it through, then you'll get an NPE on some other method and it'll be hard to find. `+++` Look at mess HTML became because of accepting every s* input.

Comment: @maaartinus Well to be fair my favourite - and most commonly used - language is C. Maybe that tells you something? Many C functions you pass NULL in some cases and many functions return NULL on error and otherwise a valid pointer. Still though the programmer should be defensive. Whether you want there to never be NULL there will be at times and it's just part of life as a programmer so better to handle it. But you say on sanity testing: fine. But that's entirely the point! It is needed to check it! I myself quite like the model that C takes but I'm biased and find its simplicity beautiful.

Comment: @Pryftan I'm very biased in favor of Java. In C, there are no exceptions, so you have to check return values and whatever. Throwing in Java is just a way to indicate a problem - somewhere up in the stack, you'll catch it, create a bug report and then fix it. *" It is needed to check it!"* - not in the above code. I (and many others) prefer to be explicit with `checkNotNull(nums)`, but letting it throw is nearly equally good. It is a check! In most places, including this one, `null` is an invalid input - it can't be shifted, can it? By disallowing it, I catch the problem near to where it starts

Comment: @maaartinus Well I also catch the problem where it starts! :) As for me I find exceptions result in spaghetti code. But hey, if it's more natural for you then all the better for you too. Meanwhile I don't have any issues checking pointers or the fact they can be used for more than one purpose. It's never been confusing to me. Pointers unfortunately are made out to be more complicated than they really need to be. Anyway we all have our likes and dislikes and styles and what's important is that we all respect that in other people. Cheers mate.